# Column Titles for UIPickerView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In a UIPickerView, is it possible to add column titles like the ones I edited into this picture below? Also, how can I left align UIPickerView text so all of the titles would fit?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may be as simple as putting a UILabel on top of your UIPickerView. If it overlaps with your content, try adding enough spaces to the right side of each number to push it to the left.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was to add 6 components, 
If component was 0 it got number from Num[0,1,2,3] ect
if component was 1 it got it from label[0] (this being the array for the text, label[Hour, Min, Sec])

so component 3 would be label[1] and so on

```
var mesurFTList = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
var mesurInchList = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]
var heightList = ["ft", "in"]

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    if component == 0 {
        let str = mesurFTList[row]
        pickerView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
        return NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white])
    }else {
        if component == 1 {
            let str = heightList[0]
            pickerView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
            return NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white])
        }else {
            if component == 2 {
                let str = mesurInchList[row]
                pickerView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
                return NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white])
            }else {
                let str = heightList[1]
                pickerView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
                return NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white])
            }
        }
    }

}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if component == 0 {
        return mesurFTList.count
    }else {
        if component == 1 {
            return 1
        }else {
            if component == 2 {
                return mesurInchList.count
            }else {
                if component == 3 {
                    return 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 260, height: 162))
let hoursLabel = UILabel()
hoursLabel.text = "Hours"
hoursLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
hoursLabel.sizeToFit()
hoursLabel.frame = CGRect(x: pickerView.frame.width * 0.30, y: pickerView.frame.height * 0.5 - (hoursLabel.frame.height / 2.0), width: hoursLabel.frame.width, height: hoursLabel.frame.height)
        pickerView.addSubview(hoursLabel)

let minLabel = UILabel()
minLabel.text = "min"
minLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
minLabel.sizeToFit()
minLabel.frame = CGRect(x: pickerView.frame.width * 0.70, y: pickerView.frame.height * 0.5 - (minLabel.frame.height / 2.0), width: minLabel.frame.width, height: minLabel.frame.height)
pickerView.addSubview(minLabel)

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == 0
    {
        return "\(hours[row])\t\t"
    }
    else if component == 1
    {
        return "\(mins[row])\t\t\t"
    }
    return "?"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the least hacky way would be to **format the numbers in the picker to include the desired label**. It's not exactly what you indicated in your image, but for the user it would result in the same degree of clarity.